# Issue with logging in using different guards in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-authentication

I'm facing an issue with implementing login functionality in Laravel, where I need to log in a user using different guards based on a specific action. Specifically, I'm trying to implement the loginAsClient feature in my ClientController, which allows an administrator to log in as a client from another part of my application.

My problem lies in the fact that even though the user seems to be logged in correctly (as confirmed by the output from info(Auth::user())), the redirection to the intended URL still redirects me to the standard login page instead of the dashboard.

```
public function loginAsClient(Request $request) {
 $id = $request->input('id');

 // Get information about the guard and intended URL
 $guard = session('guard', 'web'); // Defaults to "web" if not defined
 $urlIntended = session('url.intended', 'dashboard'); // Defaults to "dashboard" if not defined

 // Set the current guard
 Auth::shouldUse($guard);

 $user = User::find($id);

if ($user) {
    // Log in the user
    Auth::guard($guard)->loginUsingId($user->id, true);

    // Manually set the intended URL
    session(['url.intended' => $urlIntended]);

    info(Auth::user());
    info('Current URL: ' . url()->current());
    info('Intended URL: ' . session('url.intended'));

    // Redirect to the intended URL with information about the guard
    return redirect()->intended($urlIntended)->with('guard', $guard);
 } else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Client with this ID was not found.');
 }
}
```

Here is also my auth.php:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'system_users' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'system_users',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'system_users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\SystemUser::class,
    ],
```

I should note that in my Laravel application, I'm using two different tables for user authentication. For administrators, the authentication is handled by the `system_users` table, and for regular users, it's the `users` table. The guard is dynamically switched based on the user type.

In my project, I have a dual-administration setup, distinguishing between the two based on the domain. This is achieved in my `web.php` routes file, where I use different domains to route requests to the respective administration controllers.

web.php whole file:

```
$domainName = ".com";
if (env('APP_ENV') == 'local') {
    $domainName = ".local";
}
$allowedDomains = ['client' => 'client.domain'.$domainName, 'admin' => 'admin.domain'.$domainName];


    Route::group(['domain' => $allowedDomains["client"]], function () {
       Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'show'])->middleware('guest')->name('login');
       Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->middleware('guest')->name('login.perform');
    }); 

    Route::group(['domain' => $allowedDomains["admin"]], function () {
        Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'show'])->middleware('guest')->name('loginsystem');
        Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'loginSystem'])->middleware('guest')->name('loginsystem.perform');
    });

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($allowedDomains) {
Route::group(['domain' => $allowedDomains["client"]], function () {
        //Dashboard
        Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('auth');
// ...
// ...
    });
});


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:system_users'], function () use ($allowedDomains) {
    Route::group(['domain' => $allowedDomains["admin"]], function () {
// Dashboard
        Route::get('/dashboard', [CooperationController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
        Route::post('/client/login-to-client',[ClientController::class, 'loginAsClient'])->name('login-to-client');

// ...
// ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer for your question, but out of curiosity, have you considered using Roles instead? In my experience, Laravel works best when you use a single `users` table with a single `User` Model, using `roles` to differentiate a `Client` and `SystemUser` (or `Admin`, etc.). If this is a legacy system, or you've invested time into this approach, then all good, and I do hope you get this figured out! But if not, I'd recommend exploring that approach, especially since there are existing packages that do a lot of the hard work (i.e. Laravel Permissions by Spatie or similar)

Comment: could you add the whole web.php file?

Comment: @suxgri i added the requested web.php file. Have a look please.

Comment: i getting there... only one more thing i don t understand, what is the full url of the page when you make the post request to '/client/login-to-client'??? is it ```http://admin.domain.local/dashboard```?. And if that s the case you get redirected to ```http://admin.domain.local/login``` or back to ```http://admin.domain.local/dashboard```. ?